# Trying to use Salesforce Integration User License, unable to access Accounts, etc. objects

Tags: api, integration, licenses

Since a few weeks, our org has 5 free licences, of the type Salesforce Integration. This is meant for integration users. It has a few restrictions though. One of them is that the profile must be Salesforce API Only System Integrations.

By default, this user can only query objects like User and Territory2, but not Accounts, Contacts, ...

To enable that, [the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_api_integration_license.htm&release=242&type=5) states: "Use the Salesforce Integration API permission set license to extend and restrict specific user and object permissions." I assigned this permission set license to a newly created user (which also has the above mentioned license and profile) and the resulting page shows a lot of permissions given, such as:

> Accounts: Read, Create, Edit, Delete, View All, Modify All

However, the user still cannot query Accounts. I am checking this with the Workbench. The SOQL part of that does not offer Accounts (or Contacts or ...) as a possible object.

What else do I need to do to give the user access to Accounts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently that permission set license is a necessary but not a sufficient condition.

What I did: create a permission set (not a permission set license), which gives access to the Account, Contact, etc. object.

And, important: the permission set must have the License "Salesforce API Integration".

Comment: It appears that the Salesforce Integration API permission set license grants the ability to use most SObjects, but not the permissions; your custom perm set does that.  Without the permset license, you can't even add a permission that grants access to some SObjects (in my case it was Case, not Account).  However, in my testing, the custom permset does NOT need the "Salesforce API Integration" License set, once you've assigned the Permset License.  In my case, you CANNOT add CRUD for Case to a Permset with the SF Integration license, it's just not in the list.

Comment: I believe @JasonClark is correct: The Permset *license* does need to be assigned to the user, and that happens automatically when giving them the integration-only license. Separately, the perm set you create/assign that controls CRUD access does NOT need to be associated with the perm set license to grant that access via API.

Answer (score 1):

With the Salesforce API Integration license, to get access to both standard and custom objects, create a permission set  with no license selected.  Then you may add every object available.  Thats al!

Answer (score 0):

I created a Permission Set and I had an error assigning the Permission Set for the integration user, it took time to find my mistake, I made a Permission Set to the "Salesforce Integration" license, the right license to relate with the Permission Set is "Salesforce API Integration", as the correct answer in this post.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/203213)