# Was Case access removed from the Salesforce Integration License?

Tags: integration, case, licenses

We have an integration the uses an Apex Webservice to allow a backend system to access support information, including chats and cases.  When we built it in a sandbox several months ago, we decided to use the new, free "Salesforce API Only System Integration" License type.  We used a permission set to grant access to the Apex webservice class, and we used another permission set to grant CRUD and FLS on a few objects, including Case, [as outlined in this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/400074/149).  Note also the comments on that answer, one of which was from me, based on the work we did in the sandbox.

Now I'm trying to deploy this solution, and I cannot assign the object-access permission set to a user with the Integration license.  I'm getting an error,

> The user license doesn't allow the permission: View All Cases

However, I was able to assign the same permission set to a user with the same license in the sandbox.  It's the identical permission set, as it was changesetted from sandbox to prod.  Has something changed?  I can't find any documentation about such a change.

I also tried creating a new Permset and assigning it to the specific License type; in that case the Case object just isn't available in the permset editor.

Answer (score 1):

This was an oversight on my part, and is now resolved.  As outlined in the linked answer, you must assign a user with the Integration license the "Salesforce API Integration" Permission Set License *before* assigning a permission set with object permissions.  That step was missed, and I overlooked it when comparing the two orgs.  Once the integration user had the Permission Set License assigned, assigning the Permission Set with Case permissions was no issue.