# How to design Salesforce API Integration license user READ ONLY Object access of standard objects (like account, Opportunity)?

Tags: api, integration, standard-objects, licenses

I have create a new dedicated integration user with this new license "Salesforce Integration". Based on my requirements, The Integration user is need to have a READ ONLY level object access on Standard objects (like account, opportunities, product2).

After created this user alone I have tried to enable this object access via Permission set so I created the Normal Permission set with "No License" selected. But I'm unable to add that permission set into this user due to the error `This user license doesn't allow the Permission: READ: Account`

Later I can find this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/400073/trying-to-use-salesforce-integration-user-license-unable-to-access-accounts-et), I have created the Permission set with license "Salesforce API Integration" and able to add into that integration user. But this Permission set will automatically enable/add the Permission set License "Salesforce API Integration" that Permission set license will enable the "Modify all" level access on standard objects with itself.

**But I need to grant read only level object access only into my Integration user. So May I know, Is it anyway available to achieve that like providing READ ONLY access to standard objects?**.

I don't really find any help documents for this. It's will be very helpful if anyone guide me on this.

Thanks.